# How to use Release event to build and tag a docker image via GitHub CI?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I want to use GitHub release to tigger a Github CI and add the release version tag and latest tag to my image.
Here is my workflow code, but it didn't work.

````yaml
name: ci

on:
  release:
    types:
      - published

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      -
        name: Docker meta
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/img
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=release
......
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}```
````

Comment: You must login to Docker Hub or any other registry,

Comment: Yes, I have the login code in the ```......```.

Comment: Can you share the logs of the GitHub Actions workflow to help us debug why it didn't work?